# Rest API docs for High Velocity Sales

Tags: apex, high-velocity-sales

I'm trying to do some automation for adding/removing leads & contacts to cadences in the high-velocity-sales platform. I found the APIs to add or remove but I haven't found any API to list the cadences that are currently available.

Does anyone know where I can find these or if someone has done this before, can you point me to the docs?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/10/automations-for-sales-cadences-in-high-velocity-sales